# Giving a VB.net DLL reference in web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a API. I even have a dll which is written in VB. Can i give a reference of this dll to my web API project? I want to use methods n properties present in this dll. It can save my lot of time.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it. i can even debug through the code.. but there's a point were i am getting a error where it says unable to convert base 64 to something.. but the error was no were relevant to the line of code were it was throwing the error. So before asking the exact error what i was getting, i thought of asking that is it possible doing so? Do i need to add anything else or if i am missing anything? Also a request that please don't down vote the question.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted the question, but it would've been helpful if there was a comment to explain why the question was downvoted, to give you the chance to improve the question.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg : Yes true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.
So the answer to my own question is, 'YES' we can use reference of a dll which is in VB to a web API project.
I was getting an error while debugging the code was because of a silly mistake. I had to pass an entire connection string whereas i was passing only dbName of the connection string because of which that conversion error.
Thank You.